# How to compute accuracy for multi class classification problem and how is accuracy equal to weighted precision?

Tags: machine-learning, accuracy, multi-class, model-evaluation, precision

Consider the example in this article
http://text-analytics101.rxnlp.com/2014/10/computing-precision-and-recall-for.html
Will accuracy be (30 + 60 + 80)/300?
what is weighted precision?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix gives you formula for accuracy. You'll just need to substitute the values.

Comment: @SmallChess so the accuracy is calculated separately for each class?

Answer (score 9):

I've got a wonderful solution and a perfect understandable solution for this problem as I was looking for same from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081702/accuracy-precision-and-recall-for-multi-class-model)

You can calculate and store accuracy with:

```
(accuracy <- sum(diag(mat)) / sum(mat))
# [1] 0.9333333
```

Precision for each class (assuming the predictions are on the rows and the true outcomes are on the columns) can be computed with:

```
(precision <- diag(mat) / rowSums(mat))
#     setosa versicolor  virginica 
#  1.0000000  0.9090909  0.8750000
```

If you wanted to grab the precision for a particular class, you could do:

```
(precision.versicolor <- precision["versicolor"])
# versicolor 
#  0.9090909
```

Recall for each class (again assuming the predictions are on the rows and the true outcomes are on the columns) can be calculated with:

```
 recall <- (diag(mat) / colSums(mat))
    #     setosa versicolor  virginica 
    #  1.0000000  0.8695652  0.9130435
```

If you wanted recall for a particular class, you could do something like:

```
(recall.virginica <- recall["virginica"])
# virginica 
# 0.9130435
```

If instead you had the true outcomes as the rows and the predicted outcomes as the columns, then you would flip the precision and recall definitions.

Data:

```
(mat = as.matrix(read.table(text="  setosa versicolor virginica
 setosa         29          0         0
 versicolor      0         20         2
 virginica       0          3        21", header=T)))
#            setosa versicolor virginica
# setosa         29          0         0
# versicolor      0         20         2
# virginica       0          3        21
```

Answer (score 2):

Accuracy is for the whole model and your formula is correct.

Precision for **one class 'A'** is `TP_A / (TP_A + FP_A)` as in the mentioned article. Now you can calculate average precision of a model. There are a few ways of averaging (micro, macro, weighted), well explained [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html):

> 'weighted':
>   Calculate metrics for each label, and find their average, weighted by support (the number of true instances for each label). This alters ‘macro’ to account for label imbalance; (...)

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion come from the 3x3 table. But ... the link has an example on precision and recall for Label A. Accuracy is very similar.

Accuracy for A = (30 + 60 + 10 + 20 + 80) / (30 + 20 + 10 + 50 + 60 + 10 + 20 + 20 + 80)

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix

I don't know what weighted precision is about.

Comment: I do understand the denominator which is N and in numerator 30 + 60 + 80 are examples that were classified correctly, can you explain 10 + 20 in numerator?

Comment: @farheen I merely followed the formula. 60+10+20+80 = TN for label A.

Comment: They are cases that predicted for B and C, but the true labels are not A. (TN for A)

Comment: So we calculate accuracy for each label separately? then what will be the accuracy for entire model?

Answer (score 0):

Try PyCM, it gives you accuracy and other parameters.

> PyCM is a multi-class confusion matrix library written in Python
>
> ... and a proper tool for **post-classification model evaluation** that
>   supports most **classes and overall statistics parameters**.

Check the [html version](https://www.pycm.ir/test.html) of output.